# ImageView wrap_content - how to crop image

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I have the following layout, a `FrameLayout` with a nested `ImageView` with a `LinearLayout` on top:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background_circus"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_star"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XXXXXXXXXX"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="36dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

But because the image is larger than the `LinearLayout` the `FrameLayout` is stretched.

[image]

I want only the top part of the image shown (indicated by the blue selection rectangle), so the height of the `FrameLayout` should be the height of the `LinearLayout`. Is this possible without cropping the image itself?

Comment: use property of image "android:scaleType"

Comment: I already tried different combinations of ```android:scaleType``` and ```android:adjustViewBounds```. Can't get it to work, either the ```ImageView``` stretches like you see above, or the image is scaled in both width and height, I only want the width scaled.

Comment: use background not src. i think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

On your image view set the attribute `android:scaleType="fitXY"`to fit the ImageView or `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` to crop.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion is to wrap your BitmapDrawable with aClipDrawable.

ClipDrawable lets you define clipping for any other drawable, so instead of drawing the entire drawable, only a part of it will be drawn.

How would that work? Your ImageView can display a drawable - assignable through setImageDrawable(). Naturally, you would place a BitmapDrawable of your image bitmap there. If you wrap your BitmapDrawable first with ClipDrawable, and only then assign to the ImageView, you should be fine.

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
 android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:src="@drawable/clip_source" 
/>
```

and this is clip_source drawable:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:clipOrientation="vertical"
     android:drawable="@drawable/your_own_drawable"
     android:gravity="top" />
```

You can define the amount of clipping by calling the functionsetLevel() on your ClipDrawable (clip_source). A level of 0 means the image is completely hidden and a level of 10000 means the image is completely revealed. You can use any int value in the middle.

You'll have to set the level in code, so your code should first get a reference to the ClipDrawable. You can do this by runninggetDrawable() on your ImageView instance. When you have a reference to your ClipDrawable, simply run setLevel(5000) on it (or any other number 0-10000).

```
 ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     mImageDrawable = (ClipDrawable) img.getDrawable();
     mImageDrawable.setLevel(5000);
```